# Mock Service for ActivityUnitTestCase

Tags: android, android-service, android-testing

I'm trying to provide a mocked Service for an Activity in an ActivityUnitTestCase.  I've wrapped the target Context and I'm trying to intercept the `startService()` message and convert the ComponentName so that it points to my Mocked service:

```
// Wrap the Context and use a Service that reports whether methods have been called:
Context targetContext = new ContextWrapper(mInstrumentation.getTargetContext()) {
    @Override
    public ComponentName startService(Intent service) {
        // point to the mock appservice we want
        if ("com.myapp.android.service.AppService".equals(service.getComponent().getClassName())) {
            service.setComponent(new ComponentName(mInstrumentation.getContext(), MockService.class.getName()));
        } else {
            fail("Unknown service started!");
        }
        return super.startService(service);
    }
};
```

However, the Service can't be started because that component is not listed in the Manifest:

> Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.myapp.android.test/com.myapp.android.service.MockService } U=0: not found

As far as I know, test applications don't have a manifest.  Is there any way to Mock a Service for an ActivityUnitTestCase?

Comment: Test applications can have a manifest just put it in test directory or androidTest directory and you will see they merge in android studio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25738677/androidmanifest-xml-and-tests-in-android-studio

Comment: Actually I think you can merge nodes into the test manifest now.